# How to get distinct values only from django database?

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

I have the following records in table
[image: dataa]

I want to get all **sender_id** where **receiver_id** is 15 and all **receiver_id** where **sender_id** is 15.
How can I define queryset.

I have tried following

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Messages.objects.filter(Q(sender=15) | Q(receiver=15))
```

but this is giving me all the records but I want Distinct values only.

simply I want to get all the receiver id's where sender is 15 and all sender ids where receiver is 15. here my expected output is 11,17.
tell me how can I get these by defining query set.

Comment: In your query it is sender , receiver. Shouldn't it be sender_id, reciever_id ?

Comment: No that is not the issue.

Comment: `.distinct()` Read the docs: [docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)